# automatic import of existing maven dependencies

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, maven, m2eclipse, maven-3

I have maven dependency with available source code. Is it possible to import it as maven project in eclipse automatically?

I can manually create new maven project in eclipse, unpack source code in its source directory and pom file.

Are there any plugin or other tool that does such work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Maven Eclipse plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/) and tell it to download sources and javadocs for you:

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    [...]
    <plugins>
      [...]
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.8</version>
        <configuration>
          <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
          <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      [...]
    </plugins>
    [...]
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also look at [m2eclipse](http://eclipse.org/m2e/) an eclipse plugin for maven, which automagically recognizes maven projects.

Answer (score 0):

For several years Eclipse and IDEA go with Maven plugin.

For Eclipse, right-click and Maven -> Download sources. Or Ctrl+click into and IDE will download in few seconds.

This way you don't force download for all PCs as with `maven-eclipse-plugin`.